# JQuery delay() not delaying

Tags: jquery

Why does this empty the text immediately (ignoring delay)?

```
$('#error_box_text').html('error text').delay(5000).html('')
```

#### #

jQuery 1.4

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`delay` will **never** delay regular methods - only those who are pushed to the animation/effect chain. If you want to delay your `html()` call, use `queue` ( http://api.jquery.com/queue/ ):

```
$('#error_box_text').html('error text').delay(5000).queue(function() {
   $(this).html('')
});
```

It would be nice if you could do

```
$('#error_box_text').html('error text').delay(5000, function() { $(this).html('') });
```

but this isn't possible (yet).

Comment: Cheers for clearing that up been racking my brain ha.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var sel = $('#error_box_text');
sel.html('error text');
setTimeout(function(){
    sel.html('');
}, 5000);
```

See **[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**

> jQuery.delay() is best for delaying
>   between queued jQuery effects and
>   such, and is not a replacement for
>   JavaScript's native setTimeout
>   function

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
let r = $("#ur-div-id")
r.html(d)
setTimeout(() =>r.empty(), 4850);
```