# Nice, subtle, temporary highlighting technique using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a technique that isn't obnoxious like most that I've seen, that will temporarily raise attention to a small notification passage.

I've been clunking around with adding and taking away classes and wrapper divs, without much success thus far.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What do you find obnoxious about existing solutions? The Yellow Flash Technique is common and fairly unobtrusive.

Comment: I suppose the obnoxious ones I'm thinking of are mostly flash ads.  What I've been able to accomplish so far hasn't been any better than those, is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this and it works really well if you need to highlight a section after a click.

[Highlighting Named Anchors with jQuery](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/apr/17/highlighting-named-anchors-jquery/)

```
// highlight and fade background on named anchors
// requires jquery.color.js http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color
function highlight(elemId){
    var elem = $(elemId);
    elem.css("backgroundColor", "#ffffff"); // hack for Safari
    elem.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffaa' }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function(){$(elemId).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 3000)},1000);
}

if (document.location.hash) {
    highlight(document.location.hash);
}
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
    var elemId = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    highlight(elemId);
});
```

Comment: I'm sure you can take the fadein/out effect of it and use it in combination with a timed function like iamkoa posted. (I'm guessing by gradual you mean to have it slowly fade in and out)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a CSS class (.highlight, for example) that has your desired color effect, and temporarily apply the style to an element of choice:

```
$('#foo').addClass('highlight').delay(800).removeClass('highlight');
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is something I've experimented with, but was hoping for something a little more gradual, and less sudden and startling.

Comment: The number 800, what time value does it correspond with?  Is it 800 milliseconds?

Comment: jquery delay() does not work for addClass/removeClass, only for queued operations. Several solutions exist, but I found the following variation to work best for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2432770/3571110

Answer (score 1):

You are probably on the right track, just use a timer to change, and then remove the new styles that you want applied.

Have a look at the second setTimeout example on this page for inspiration.

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

### Edit

What I think you want is a fade in, fade out type effect.  This could be accomplished by having a couple classes representing states between default and highlighted.  Wait a couple seconds after load, move to slightly highlighted, wait a 10th of a second and highlight it a little more, then in another 10th of a second full highlight, keep it there for a second or two, and then in 10th second intervals move backwards through your classes.  This is just an example, but with some tuning you could make this as 'gradual' as you like.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, this is close to what I've been trying out, but need something more gradual.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by gradual?

Comment: Similar to the fadeIn() and fadeOut() effects.